# Permissions en SDK Facebook 3.0

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, permissions

I am using the new SDK Facebook 3.0. I know that when I want to request permissions (no basic), I have to set it in the LoginButton like that:

```
 signInFBButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email"));
```

But I don't know how to do that when I don't use the LoginButton. I am using openActiveSession() in order to open the session, but I have to take the e-mail and I don´t know how to do that without LoginButton.

Any help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [Session.OpenRequest](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/Session.OpenRequest) (it uses the builder pattern).

```
Session.OpenRequest openRequest = new Session.OpenRequest(this);
openRequest.setPermissions(...)
           .setCallback(...);
```

then create a new Session and set it as the active session

```
Session session = new Session(this);
Session.setActiveSession(session);
```

finally, open the session you just created

```
session.openForRead(openRequest);
```